# Can Ubuntu Mobile be installed on a Nokia Lumnia 800?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware will the Ubuntu Mobile OS support?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236276/what-hardware-will-the-ubuntu-mobile-os-support)

Can I install the Ubuntu Mobile operating system on a Nokia Lumnia 800?

This phone has 512 MB of memory 512 and the a 1.4 GHz CPU.

Comment: It would rely on the drivers, I am very interested myself too, I want to run this on my galaxy s2.

Comment: I've edited your question mentioning [Ubuntu Mobile](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone). Just to be sure, are you willing to install that or [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android)?

Comment: Is this really On topic?, I mean the thing was just **announced** not even released, no dates, no specs, no requirements, not anything. How is anyone really going to have an answer?.